# My mesh flips out whenever I move the timeline cursor

Tags: modeling, mesh, blend-files

[image: The model just flips upside down for some reason!]

Here's the .blend file. https://www.dropbox.com/s/m8ka7jcygfijx4r/buggymusket.blend?dl=0

I really am clueless.

Basically, I have two seperate bones attached to the mesh. The mesh has two vertex groups, one 'hammer' and 'ignition'.

The hammer seems to move fine on my end, and yet when I try doing anything with the ignition, it flips out.

If anyone can help me, I'll give them a cookie!!

Comment: it's a bit hard to understand... first of all, why do you have 2 armatures (hammer and ignition), why not one armature with the 2 bones (hammer and ignition)?

Comment: I had assumed this was the only way to do two different joints. How can I have them disconnected while at the same time being apart of the same armature?

Comment: I don't know what you're supposed to do with your gun, maybe create one big bone for the whole gun, create 2 small bones for hammer and ignition, parent them to the big one

Comment: and parent the whole gun to the big bone, except hammer and ignition, then parent hammer and ignition to their own bone. Use the bones pivot points as the hammer and ignition pivot points

Comment: Is blender always this finnicky?

Comment: it is just logical   ;)